# 'If match then print that there is a match if not run index match function' not working

Tags: google-sheets

I know I'm missing something but I can't figure out why this won't work:

```
=if(match('Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!C2,'Home Services - Interiors'!E2:E,0),""&'Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!D2&" is a duplicate",index('Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!2:1000,match('Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!C1,'Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!C1:C,0)))
```

This function is supposed to search a broader database for a matching phone number which if it doesn't find it is supposed to go to the if false clause of the function. It keeps throwing an `#N/A` error when the phone number is not present. If I wrap it in an `IFNA` function instead of `IF` then it will work but I can't run the index function.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to test it without your specific data but this is how I would fix it
I would wrap the first `match` with `ifna` and return `False` as default value if no match is found. This will enable the `IF` logic to progress and not get stuck on `#N/A`.

```
=if(ifna(match('Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!C2,'Home Services - Interiors'!E2:E,0),False),""&'Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!D2&" is a duplicate",index('Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!2:1000,match('Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!C1,'Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!C1:C,0)))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! worked like a charm. I'm not quite following how but I think I can figure it out. Is it that if the `#N/A` error happens then it's basically assigned to `False` and if it's `False` then it returns `""&'Hunter Douglas CA ready for BU'!D2&" is a duplicate".? Am I following that right? Again Thanks!

Comment: Yep, if there is a match for the first `match` then it will return `True`, if there is no match then it will return `#N/A`. But we wrapped `ifna` around it so it returns `False` instead. And from the `True` or `False` result the `IF` logic can either return `duplicate record` or the second `match`